# How do I mock a File.copyTo in Mockito and Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito, mockk

Simply put, I've got a `File` object that product code will invoke the `copyTo` method on.  Similarly, I'm looking for an equivalent mocking technique for `File.inputStream`

In the unit test, I just want a mock file and the copyTo call to be a no-op or at best verified.

Simple example:

```
    fun copyFileTest() {
        println("start test")
        val mockFileSrc = mock(File::class.java)
        val mockFileDst = mock(File::class.java)

        `when`(mockFileSrc.exists()).doReturn(true)
        `when`(mockFileSrc.copyTo(any(), any(), any())).thenAnswer { // DOES NOT WORK
            val result = it.arguments[0]
            result as File
        }

        println("done initializing mocks")

        Assert.assertEquals(mockFileSrc.exists(), true)
        mockFileSrc.copyTo(mockFileDst, true, 0)

        println("done with test")
    }
```

When the unit test runs, this exception is thrown:

```
Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.io.FilesKt__UtilsKt.copyTo, parameter target
java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.io.FilesKt__UtilsKt.copyTo, parameter target
    at kotlin.io.FilesKt__UtilsKt.copyTo(Utils.kt)
    at com.selibe.myapp.foo.WorkerTest.copyFileTest(WorkerTest.kt:121) <34 internal lines>
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy5.processTestClass(Unknown Source) <7 internal lines>
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74
```

I believe the problem may be related to the fact that `copyTo` seems to be an extension function.

What's the easiest way to just make copyTo a no-op in the unit test that always succeeds in the unit test?

mockito or mockk solutions are acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is that `File.copyTo` is a [Kotlin extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/copy-to.html). Mockito is a Java framework, and doesn't understand anything about Kotlin extension functions.

Java doesn't support extension functions, so what `File.copyTo` actually compiles to in JVM bytecode is a static function, a member of class `kotlin.io.UtilsKt`, which takes an extra argument at the start of the argument list, representing the receiver object (the source file), like this:

```
public static final File copyTo(
        File $this$copyTo,
        File target,
        boolean overwrite,
        int bufferSize)
```

If you want to use Mockito to mock this, you'll need to use [mockStatic](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#static_mocks) on the `kotlin.io.UtilsKt` class and then mock the static method `copyTo`. It would be much easier to switch to a mocking framework that is written for Kotlin, such as [Mockk](https://mockk.io/), if that is possible.

When using Mockk, to mock module-wide extension functions, use `mockkStatic` as per the [instructions on the Mockk website](https://mockk.io/#extension-functions). Here's the equivalent of your original code, translated to use Mockk:

```
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.mockk
import io.mockk.mockkStatic
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import java.io.File

class MyTest {
    @Test
    fun copyFileTest() {
        println("start test")
        val mockFileSrc = mockk<File>()
        val mockFileDst = mockk<File>()

        mockkStatic(File::copyTo)
        every { mockFileSrc.exists() } returns true
        every { mockFileSrc.copyTo(any(), any(), any()) } answers {
            arg(1) as File  // arg(0) is `this` (source), arg(1) is dest
        }

        println("done initializing mocks")

        assertTrue(mockFileSrc.exists())
        mockFileSrc.copyTo(mockFileDst, true, 0)

        println("done with test")
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance you can share a Mockk example specific to `File.copyTo` or `File.inputStream`. I'm still not getting this. :(

Comment: @selbie see updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using the **[mockk](https://mockk.io/)** library. There is Kotlin extension function support. **Java** does not support extension functions. You are trying to use `extension function` in your code.

**Sample UseCase**

```
import io.mockk.mockkStatic

@Test
    fun `copy to cache should copy file to right folder`() {
        // Given
        val context = mockk<Context>(relaxed = true)
        every { context.cacheDir.path } returns "folder/"

        mockkStatic("kotlin.io.FilesKt__UtilsKt")
        every { any<File>().copyTo(any(), any(), any()) } returns mockk(relaxed = true)

        val source = File("image.jpg")

        // When
        copyToCache(context, File("image.jpg"))

        // Then
        verify {
            source.copyTo(File("folder/compressor/image.jpg"), true, any())
        }
    }
```

You can use other extension functions as you wish.

**Your Case**

```
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.mockk
import io.mockk.mockkStatic
import java.io.File

    class CopyTestFile {
        @Test
        fun `copy to file`() {
            
            val mockFileSrc = mockk<File>()
            val mockFileDst = mockk<File>()
    
            mockkStatic("kotlin.io.FilesKt__UtilsKt")
            every { mockFileSrc.exists() } returns true
            every { mockFileSrc.copyTo(any(), any(), any()) } answers {
                arg(0) as File
            }
    
            assertTrue(mockFileSrc.exists())
            mockFileSrc.copyTo(mockFileDst, true, 0)
        }
    }
```

To support @K314159's answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm definitively not gonna win points here, but I can't stop wondering... Why are you trying to mock classes that can totally work in an unit test?

Because jUnit has a access to java apis. And kotlin apis.

All your cache code needs to be JVM complaint is to remove the hard dependency to the android jar. In other words:

```
val context = mockk<Context>(relaxed = true)
        every { context.cacheDir.path } returns "folder/"
```

cacheDir.path is an String. Your method should receive a String as an argument, not directly read an android context. Then you get to run your code directly, no mocks needed, and try all the corner cases you may run into. Or stress test the hell out of your code.

I did that at my latest position. I had to make sure 4 separate processes, all capable of accessing the same files and directories, would not crash among themselves. So I made a JVM implementation, and subclassed it to add the android-only stuff, like accessing context.
The tests run 11 thousand operations in concurrently. So I know it works. And yes, moving and copying files were part of the tested operations. And copyTo is one of the APIs I used.

Remember, you aren't tied to android. You are a JVM developer. Android is just your main environment.

Comment: This is a very fair point. It's a path I've gone down before in some other projects. And almost the path I went down with what I'm working on now.  Or as I like to say, "why mock the file system when you can just use the file system".  That is to have the unit test run the code out of a temporary directory instead of the real application folder.  And then the test setup configures the temp directory and seeds the files expected.